# having trouble with .next method making a casear cipher

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm not worried about what happens if my key will go past Z right now, or capital letters. All I want is my outcome to be something like. text=abc  key=2 and it print "cde". Where am I going wrong?

```
puts "What would you like to cipher?"
text = gets.chomp
puts " what number key would you like?"
key = gets.chomp.to_i

def casear_cipher(text,key)
  ciphered_text = []
  text.chars.each do |letter|
    ciphered_text = letter
    ciphered_text = ciphered_text.next
  end
end

puts casear_cipher(text,key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the key yet, so it will always just do abc -> bcd. If you're really not concerned about "Z" going to "AA", you can try this:

```
def cipher(text, key)    
  text.chars.map { |c| (c.ord + key).chr }.join
end
```

Comment: care to explain ord? So far I understand it as. text, char makes an array, map goes through every part of the array. { |c| (c.ord + key).chr } <<<<<this I do not understand.

Comment: ord turns it into the ascii value and chr turns it back - or rather the integer ordinal value to be exact.

Comment: You can find that method here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-ord

Comment: I'm new to Ruby when it comes to loops, I've been dealing with JS for a while. Is the |c| just the iterator? it could be "i" or any letter? I get the rest now.

Comment: Yeah it could be anything, it's a variable that will contain each of the `char`s from text. Could be anything like `single_char` e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Since `'Z'.next => 'AA'` and `'z'.next #=> 'aa'`, we can use `[-1]` to select the last letter.

In the code below we perform `next!` on each character `n` times using the `times` method. `next!` modifies the character whereas `next` does not.

```
def casear_cipher(text, n)
  text.chars.map do |c| n.times { c.next! }
    c[-1]
  end.join
end

p casear_cipher('abc',2)   #=> "cde"
p casear_cipher('xyz',2)   #=> "zab"
p casear_cipher('ZEBRA',2) #=> "BGDTC"
```

More information about these methods can be found at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/

Comment: Cool but how does -1  work? I don't understand how it resets the alphabet back to "a"?

Comment: @JacobMoore `'hello'[0]` gets the letter at index 0, namely `'h'`. `'hello'[-1]` gets the last letter, namely `'o'`.  `'z'.next #=> "aa"` then `'z'.next[-1] #=> "a" ` .

Comment: Wouldn't [-1] make a "z" become "y"? Or if it gets the last letter in an index wouldn't it just be z? I need to read up on indexing...

Comment: @JacobMoore Try the examples in my previous comment in irb and you can see how they work. The only thing I can now suggest is work through some ruby tutorials which cover indexing and methods like `map`. Hope this helps.